# csrf_token verification failed or aborted error with form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm getting CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
My index view:

```py
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'tasks':tasks,'form':form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/list.html', context)
```

My `list.html` template with form:

```
<h3>TO DO</h3>
<form method="POST" action="/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.title }}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Create Task">
</form>
{% for task in tasks %}
  <div>
    <p>{{ task }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why do you use `name=""` in the submit button?

Comment: You're including CSRF in the form, so it's very difficult to say why you'd get an error from this. We can however say that an invalid form will never be rendered so a user will never see errors from their form submission.

Comment: also the same result after removing name attribute

Comment: @markwalker_ then what's the solution for it.

Comment: Only run the redirect if the form was saved. So just indent that line. If it fails validation, your posted form (with it's errors still there) will be rendered again